# How to streamline memory object equality comparison in Entity Framework condition?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, equality

If I load an object through Entity Framework, and persist it to later use it - for example in an equality filter - Entity Framework throws the following error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyType'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

This can then easily be solved by using an identifying value/value combination on `MyType`, such as `.Where(x => x.Name == MyTypeMemoryInstance.Name)`.

However, I was wondering if there is an alternative to allow the equality comparison without having to provide the primitive type so I can do `.Where(x => x == MyTypeMemoryInstance)` instead, and still do so in SQL rather than in memory.

Conceptually, this could be solved if I can provide the LINQ-to-SQL translation with the specific primitive type comparison to use for a given type, similar to overriding regular equality comparison in C#, but I don't know if this is actually possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can think of, because in where clause you have Func would be:

```
public class MyType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Func<MyType, bool> GetQuery()
    {
        // or whatever equals you would like
        return x => x.Name == this.Name && x.Id == this.Id;
    }
}
```

Then use it like for example:

```
var first = ctx.MyTypes.First();
var listContainingLoadedThings = ctx.MyTypes.Where(first.GetQuery()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Linq to Entities queries are translated to SQL. The Linq provider can't convert two object instances to compare them in sql. That's why it throw that exception, because it needs to work with primitive types as you do in SQL.

One solution can be using `AsEnumerable` extension method, to make the switch from Linq to Entities to Linq to Objects. If you do something like:

```
var query=context.YourDbSet.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x== MyTypeMemoryInstance)....
```

But be careful with this solution. You are going to load all the rows from that table to memory. Another partial solution could be if you have more than one condition then you could apply some filters first and later apply the instance comparison if you really need to do so:

```
var query=context.YourDbSet.Where(...).AsEnumerable().Where(x => x== MyTypeMemoryInstance)....
```

Comment: Thank you - yes, I know about the in-memory comparison but really wanted to automate this in the SQL translation instead. Essentially I was hoping that the LINQ to SQL provider can be made aware of (via IComparer, attribute, etc.) what I want to use for equality comparison and use that when resolving the equality comparison expression.

Comment: I'm afraid that comparison is not possible at server level :(. But why you can't compare multiples properties from both objects instead compare instances? As far I know it doesn't exist anything yet that allows you define how to treat/translate an object instance to be compared in  sql